# Picklist error when added, removed and added again an option

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, picklist

I've got a problem with picklist from jquery.
Here is an example of my problem : http://jsfiddle.net/QzjTs/344/

```
$("#form").pickList();

$('#lesson').submit(function(msg) {
    alert($('#form').val());
});
```

If I select Option 1 and save it, I've got the correct value which is 30.
But if i remove it and add it another time and save it, I've got 'null' instead of 30.

have you got an idea to solve this issue ?

Thank's a lot

Comment: I added Option1 and saved, alert 30. Next I removed Option1, readded Option1 and saved, alert 30. Cant really reproduce your problem from the fiddle

Comment: Thanks for the reply, strange to have different results ... i'm going to search for an other solution

Comment: what OS are you running, is it a Mac?

Comment: I'm using Windows.
i found the solution here : https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-ui-picklist/issues/16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for me here : https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-ui-picklist/issues/16

Thanks for the help